# How to add random animation effect in owl carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

This is my code and effect to the owl carousel

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
              autoplay:true,
              autoplayTimeout:2000,
              autoplayHoverPause:true,
              dots: true,
              merge:false,
              loop:true,
              items:1,
              animateOut: 'bounce',
              animateIn: 'zoomIn',
          });
        });
```

Insted of using only one animation here

```
animateOut: 'bounce',
animateIn: 'zoomIn',
```

I want to use random animation here.How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getRandomAnimation(){
    var animationList = ['bounce', 'zoomIn']; 
    return animationList[Math.floor(Math.random() * animationList.length)];
}    

$(document).ready(function(){
      let props = {
          autoplay:true,
          autoplayTimeout:2000,
          autoplayHoverPause:true,
          dots: true,
          merge:false,
          loop:true,
          items:1
      };

      props['animateOut'] = getRandomAnimation();
      props['animateIn'] = getRandomAnimation();

      $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel(props);
});
```

Comment: this only randomizes the initial settings, if you want to randomize the effect on each slide right now the only way is to change the source code of owl

Answer (score 1):

@ykaragol's answer does creates random property but on on first load only, like me if you are also looking to have random animation each time slider changes then do the following changes in owl carousel library file (Note: I am using Owl Carousel v2.1.0 the code might be different in other version):

Find `this.core.settings.animateIn` it should in in 2 places in first one the code will be like this:

```
        var left,
        clear = $.proxy(this.clear, this),
        previous = this.core.$stage.children().eq(this.previous),
        next = this.core.$stage.children().eq(this.next),
        incoming = this.core.settings.animateIn,
        outgoing = this.core.settings.animateOut;
```

Go ahead and add this code right after that:

```
        if(incoming.constructor == Array){
            incoming = incoming[Math.floor(Math.random() * incoming.length)];
        }

        if(outgoing.constructor == Array){
            outgoing = outgoing[Math.floor(Math.random() * outgoing.length)];
        }
```

Now find `this.core.settings.animateIn` again in file and it will be around code like this:

```
    $(e.target).css( { 'left': '' } )
        .removeClass('animated owl-animated-out owl-animated-in')
        .removeClass(this.core.settings.animateIn);
        .removeClass(this.core.settings.animateOut);
    this.core.onTransitionEnd();
```

Change that to this:

```
    var incoming = this.core.settings.animateIn;
    var outgoing = this.core.settings.animateOut

    if(incoming.constructor == Array){
        for (var i = incoming.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            $(e.target).removeClass(incoming[i]);
        }
    }else{
        $(e.target).removeClass(this.core.settings.animateIn);
    }
    if(outgoing.constructor == Array){
        for (var i = outgoing.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            $(e.target).removeClass(outgoing[i]);
        }
    }else{
        $(e.target).removeClass(this.core.settings.animateOut);
    }

    $(e.target).css( { 'left': '' } )
        .removeClass('animated owl-animated-out owl-animated-in');
    this.core.onTransitionEnd();
```

Now this should work simply by passing an array of animation to animate property like this:

```
    $owlSty1.owlCarousel({
        animateOut: ['slideOutDown', 'zoomOut'],
        animateIn: ['flipInX', 'zoomIn'],
        loop: true,
        nav: false,
        items: 1,
        dots: true,
        responsive: false,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 6000,
        rtl: directionRTL
    });
```

Comment: Hey. I tried your answer out with the latest owl carousel and it works. Just trying to figure out how it works. Best regards.

Comment: I did submitted this feature on github rep & this might help you understand: https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/pull/1794/files